# (solved) getting post author's user role

Tags: posts, user-roles, author

we can use

```
$user = wp_get_current_user();
    if ( !in_array( 'administrator', (array) $user->roles ) )
```

to get the user role of the viewer. but i want to ignore who views. i want to get who writes the post. need something like

```
$user = wp_get_post_author();
    if ( !in_array( 'administrator', (array) $user->roles ) )
```

so that i can show results depending on the user who writes the post while ignoring who views that.

Comment: Where are you doing that - in the frontend or backend? And what is the problem with your example (besides not using [`get_the_author()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_author/))?

Comment: @kero We need the WP_User object and get_the_author just returns the display name.

Comment: What are you trying to do? If you are counting post views, but want to ignore the author, then this is the completely wrong approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the author's ID on the post and fetch their user object from that with get_userdata(), e.g.

```php
$author = get_userdata( get_post()->post_author ) ;
if ( !in_array( 'administrator', (array) $author->roles ) ) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried so hard and got so far
But in the end it doesn't even matter

```
$post_id = get_queried_object_id();
$author_ID = get_post_field( 'post_author', $post_id );
$authorData = get_userdata( $author_ID );
if ( !in_array( 'administrator', $authorData->roles)){... ...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve the current user object from the wp_get_current_user() and then check administrator role in in_array.

```
$user = wp_get_current_user();
if ( in_array( 'administrator', (array) $user->roles ) ) {
    //The user has the "administrator" role
}
```

Here I have shared the link for [wp_get_current_user()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_current_user/) and [in_array()](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_in_array.asp) for better understanding.